# empty() doesn't work with codeigniter input class

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

This is really weird.
Whenever I call something like

```
if(empty($this->input->post("foo")){//blabla}
```

The whole PHP is "down" and I get a blank page from the website (even when I don't pass through this empty(input) line).

I know this is not the right method and it is stupid, I change the code to

```
if(!$this->input->post("foo")){//blabla}
```

Better I guess ?

Seriously, how come the empty(input) breaks down the entire PHP page ? (I can't get any echo "something").

Comment: turn error_reporting and displayr_errors ON , maybe is some other error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `empty` with functions, and neither do you need to. `empty` is a special construct that only works on variables and triggers a fatal error otherwise. See [The Definitive Guide To isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> ***Note***:
>
> empty() only checks **variables** as anything else will result in a parse
>   error. In other words, the following will not work:
>   empty(trim($name)).

Update:
From php 5.5, empty() supports expressions too.

> Changelog:
>
> 5.5.0 empty() now supports expressions, rather than only variables.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use empty with input class because if the post variable does not exists or contains null value input class returns false which automatically fails the if condition and your else block would work...